# Excel 2007 from C# get_Value always returns -2146826265

Tags: c#, excel, vba, excel-2007

I have a small C# app that references the Microsoft Excel 12.0 Object Library. Among other things, it reads a value from an Excel cell. It reads this value from some older Excel (.xls) files and some 2007 files (.xlsx). The value comes back properly for all .xls files but I only get the following value for .xlsx files: -2146826265.

The cell I'm reading contains a simple formula: "=A1+B1".

This is the line of code I'm using

```
((Excel.Range)ws.Cells.get_Item(29, 17)).get_Value(null));
```

Where ws is the current, active worksheet.

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: -2146826265 looks uncomfortably like an error code. Re-express it as an unsigned hexadecimal constant and google it in the context of C# or Excel.

Answer (score 11):

The get_value function returns integer for his error message.
Here is the list :

```
-2146826281 = #Div/0!
-2146826246 - #N/A
-2146826259 = #Name?
-2146826288 = #Null!
-2146826252 = #Num!
-2146826265 = #Ref!     <- yours !
-2146826273 = #Value!
```

And here is a very good article :

http://xldennis.wordpress.com/2006/11/22/dealing-with-cverr-values-in-net-%E2%80%93-part-i-the-problem/

From this very good answer :

[How to know if a cell has an error in the formula in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424718/how-to-know-if-a-cell-has-an-error-in-the-formula-in-c/2425170#2425170)