# Updated Excel Cell value by Name Reference in C#

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I have a named cell in excel lets say its called "myCell"
In C# I wish to be able to access this cell and update its value.
I've tried

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Names.Item(@"myCell").Value = "myValue";
```

But this throws a COM exception with the message 'Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Names.Item(@"myCell")
```

does not return a Range for which you can set the value, but an object of type Name. You can get the Range representing the cell you are looking for using the RefersToRange property and then set the value for this object. This all translates into something like this:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Names.Item(@"myCell").RefersToRange.Value = "myValue";
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `Range` object. A named cell is a named `Range`, so this should work:

```
myWorkBook.myWorkSheet.Range["myCell"].Value = "myValue";
```

P.D. I have no way to check this and I'm not sure if you can assign the value directly to a `Range`object or you need to specify the offset of the cell inside the `Range` (as it can contain many cells).

You can also try: (I dont remember if named ranges work directly with cells)

```
myWorkBook.myWorkSheet.Cells["myCell"].Value = "myValue";
```

Comment: Both give the message Non-invocable member 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Application.Range' cannot be used like a method.

Comment: @Eddie: Oops, change those `(` with `[`. Editted my post.

Comment: Still triggers the same message with []

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
var cell = myWorksheet.Evaluate("defined_name");
if (cell != null) { cell.Value = "hello"; }
```

Or:

```
myWorksheet.Cells.SetValue("defined_name", "hello");
```

In the last case, trying to set a value for a non-existing name gives "Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

If checking for `null` doesn't work, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166876/excel-2007-from-c-sharp-get-value-always-returns-2146826265) for a list of int values as errors.