# How to determine error value in cell similar to VBA.IsError

Tags: vb.net, excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet. I'm trying to test whether the formula results in an error. VBA has `VBA.IsError` and I'm looking for an equivalent in VB.net.

```
    Dim CurrCell As Excel.Range = ws.Range("B10")
    CurrCell.Formula = "=DATEVALUE(-1)" 'results in #VALUE! error
    CurrCell.Select()

    'doesn't detect error
    If Microsoft.VisualBasic.IsError(CurrCell.Value) Then
        Debug.Print("error")
    Else
        Debug.Print("not error")
    End If

    'doesn't detect error; shows as VariantType.Integer
    Debug.Print(VarType(CurrCell.Value))
    If VarType(CurrCell.Value) = VariantType.Error Then
        Debug.Print("error")
    Else
        Debug.Print("not error")
    End If
```

How do I detect whether the result of the formula is an error using VB.net?

Comment: tried using [WorksheetFunction.IsError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff835263.aspx) ?

Comment: @WhiteHat Oh thanks! Not sure why I didn't think of it.

Comment: @WhiteHat if you post it as an answer I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: cheers! @D_Bester can have it, looks good to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
    If xlApp.WorksheetFunction.IsError(CurrCell) Then
        Debug.Print("error")
    Else
        Debug.Print("not error")
    End If
```

But a much [better solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2425170/2559297) was given by Mike Rosenblum

```
    Public Shared Function IsError(ByVal rgValue As Object) As Boolean
        Return TypeOf (rgValue) Is Int32
    End Function
```

[Dealing with CVErr Values in .NET – Part I: The Problem](https://xldennis.wordpress.com/2006/11/22/dealing-with-cverr-values-in-net-%E2%80%93-part-i-the-problem/)

[Dealing with CVErr Values in .NET – Part II: Solutions](https://xldennis.wordpress.com/2006/11/29/dealing-with-cverr-values-in-net-part-ii-solutions/)