# Worksheet Function.CountIfs(...) in C# return value is a 2 dim Object Array

Tags: c#, arrays, excel, object, worksheet-function

My Problem is that i want to use the `WorksheetFunction` method `CountIf` in C# for Excel.

And I'm always getting an 2 dim object array from that function

```
double[,] zn1 = wsf.CountIfs(cSheet.Range[cSheet.Cells[13, 1],
     cSheet.Cells[20, 1]], sName + sName);
```

(It works only with `double[,] zn1` or `var zn1`, otherwise I'm getting an error that the object array `obj[,]` can't be converted to a `double` or `double[]`, `string[]` etc.")

where `wsf` is defined as

```
Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
Excel.WorksheetFunction wsf = xl.WorksheetFunction;
```

So when I run it, I'm getting a 2 dim object array, which has the same length as the Range, I'm looking for, and all entries contain the same number "-2146826273".

And If I convert the array to a 1 dim double array, the return is `System.Double[]`.

```
object[] to = zn1.Cast<object>().ToArray();
object[] res = to as object[];
double[] sRes;
sRes = res.OfType<double>().ToArray();
```

All other `WorksheetFunction` methods  are working well and without errors.

So my question is how, do I get an normal value for the `WorksheetFunction` method  `CountIfs(...)`?

And yes I have to use `WorksheetFunction` methods and I can't enter it like a Formula with a string.

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... I found the problem.

It has to be like this:

```
var xl = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;
Excel.WorksheetFunction wsf = xl.WorksheetFunction;
```

and not like that:

```
Excel.Application xl = new Excel.Application();
Excel.WorksheetFunction wsf = xl.WorksheetFunction;
```

Comment: It is interesting, would be great to know why this has worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your formula, the error number ("-2146826273") indicates that the problem is within the formula.

See here for [formula error checking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424718/how-to-know-if-a-cell-has-an-error-in-the-formula-in-c-sharp) and particular [error](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/How-to-correct-a-VALUE-error-15e1b616-fbf2-4147-9c0b-0a11a20e409e).

Comment: The funny thing is if i write this formula in vba it's working fine.
But i have to do it in C#

I have checked the formula for that error and I tried to change the format for the cells but it's not helping.
It says also that a closed Workbook could be that problem for ("-2146826273") = #VALUE!, but it's always open.

Comment: As you said the other WorkssheetFunctions are working so that should not be the open workbook issue. I think I would start with a very simple CountIfs in the formula to verify if this very simple case gets through.

Comment: I have tried the formula with simple CountIfs like: "32", <32, simple words, and also with empty cells, but the error ("-2146826273") stays the same. 
I have also tried CountIf and it's not working. 

And if I use CountIf(s) like this: 
`Worksheet.Range[...] = "= COUNTIFS(Range Arg1, Object Arg2)";`
it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code for the countif - this is working

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
Excel.Application excelapp = new Excel.Application();

double count = excelApp.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(range, Criteria);
```

returns a double with count