# What is the underlying type of Value2?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-2016

I was wondering what kind of types of Value2 can be returned. I am asking this question since it seems that the type of Value2 is always an object, but the actual underlying type does not always seem to be the same.
For example: given that cell A1 contains “1234”, the following line of code fails on my computer:

```
string targetValue = (string)Application.get_Range(“A1”).Value2
```

However, if the cell A1 contains “abcdef”, the previous line succeeds. Now, I have seen the type double and the type string. My question is, are there more possible types that can result in an error? Does Value2 have for example integers? Or have I caught them all?

I have read the documentation, but I can't seem to find all possible supported types.

PS: I am using Visual Studio 2017, Excel 2016 and C# to create my add-in.

[Documentation regarding Ranges](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ad4d8d6.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only difference between the **Value2** property and the **Value** property is that the **Value2** property doesn't use the `Currency` and `Date` data types. You can return values formatted with these data types as floating-point numbers by using the Double data type.

See [Range.Value2 Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.value2)

Comment: I am aware that the Value2 property is a Variant in VBA, but in C#, we do not seem to have Variant as native types.But if I infer correctly from your answer, Value2 can only contain a double or a string, am I correct?

Comment: @Snowflake a similar version of variant exist in C# and it's called `Dynamic. On the other side `object` is also very similar to variant. It can be anything.It's up to you to unboxed the value when you want to what you want.

Comment: @Snowflake Data types are different in Excel and VBA.  In particular, the Date and Currency data types do not really exist in Excel, but are converted to those VBA data types when you read the `.Value` property of a range object.  So `Value2` can contain empty, string, error, number (double) or boolean.  Ted Williams has an excellent discussion of [Value, Value2 and text](https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/11/30/text-vs-value-vs-value2-slow-text-and-how-to-avoid-it/)

Comment: Based on some further experimentation, I came to the conclusion that VTSO C# in Excel only has several types, null, string, int (which is only gotten through an error, I haven't been able to get this using any other way), double or boolean.

Comment: @Snowflake Suggest you post a new question with the specific code that is causing the problem, along with examples of data, expected output, actual output and any error messages

Comment: @Ron, I am not having a particular problem, but I only wanted to say that if your formula contains an error, like "=AAAAA", which results in a #NAME error in Excel, it would result in an int in the C# VTSO code.

Comment: @Snowflake And if you have an `int32`  you can infer that there is an error in the cell!  See @Mike Rosenbloom's answer in [How to know if a cell has an error in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2424718/how-to-know-if-a-cell-has-an-error-in-the-formula-in-c-sharp)